# Is there a way to kill all applications and restart the Mac from the terminal?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, terminal, restart

Is there a code to run in the terminal that I can use to close all applications and restart the mac? I am currently using "osascript -e 'tell app \"System Events\" to restart" to cause a restart, but it isn't closing the applications. - I need for the code to all be in one command, so I can put it in my code without one canceling out the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutdown` will close the apps automatically for you (they may not save their working files, however):

Shutdown:

```
$ sudo shutdown -s now
```

Restart:

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Is there a way to link that with the restart command? I need them all to be on the same command line - So that it closes all apps, and restarts.

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale That will do a restart for you (`-r` option) and thereby close all apps, but as I say, it will probably "hard kill" (`kill -9`) the apps, so work may be lost.

Comment: When I use "$ sudo shutdown -r now" it says command not found, when I use "sudo shutdown -r now" it ask for my password. I need to be able to run the restart and close apps without asking for a password.

Comment: The `$` at the beginning of his answer's code is suposed to represent the command prompt; it's **not** part of what you have to type (and it's common practice when writing terminal commands on documentation - some people use `%`).

Comment: And I don't think you can just force-shut down the computer without the user's consent or an admin password; imagine all the damage and trouble that a malicious attacker could do if that were the case.